# Dedicated ebook reader?

Tags: epub, ebook-readers, pdf

I'm looking for a device that allows me to read ebooks, but I don't want it to do much, if anything, else. So something that has a dedicated ebook reading design and functionality (so for example *not* the Nexus 7 or an iPad), what are my options?

Additional requirements: Supports reading my own PDFs and ePubs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The device that you need is basically an [e-ink ereader](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-book_reader), all of them have the features that you have requested.

Since there are many different brands and models, each one with its own set of different features, I suggest you to take a look at the comparison page on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_readers), that has in one place all the informations that you need to make your choice; if you understand italian, also look on [eBookReaderItalia](http://modelli.ebookreaderitalia.com/) (anyway it's just a table filled with tech specs, so even if you don't speak my language you should be able to understand it nonetheless).

There is also another comparison page on [Mobileread wiki](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/E-book_Reader_Matrix), but it is a bit outdated .

Comment: It might be good to pull info on the major models directly into this answer.

Comment: These pages get updated fairly often, so I think it's best to point out where to find informations rather than posting here some specs that would be surpassed every time that a new model comes out.

Comment: @Sekhemty Instead of using strikeouts, it would be best if you deleted the incorrect text and only stated the correct answer. It's your answer, so you can disregard this suggestion, but cleaning it up would make it more helpful to future visitors.

Comment: I tried to rewrite it and keep also the old link, that could be useful for reference as well.

Answer (score 5):

Any of the Sony Reader devices are pretty much dedicated to reading ebooks. The current [PRST3BC_CA](http://store.sony.ca/reader-with-integrated-snap-cover-zid31-PRST3//cat-31-catid-All-eReaders?vva_ColorCode=000000&_t=pfm=category) model has the following specifications (for full specs, follow the link):

[image]

I've been using the [Sony Reader PRS-650](http://reviews.cnet.com/e-book-readers/sony-reader-touch-edition/4505-3508_7-34167293.html) for a few years now and I'm very happy with it.

Comment: There are not much supported formats.