# Looking for recommendation on eBook reader for university textbooks

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers

I'm looking for a eBook reader to carry around with me for studying and reading science textbooks and papers. I was interested in kindle because of the e-ink technology. Briefly what I'm looking is :

- I don't want a bright, eye-soaring tablets however I read that kindle does not fully support MathML.My priority is to read textbooks without getting my eyes tired.
- I'd like to take notes but that is not very important.
- Same goes for wifi connection.

  I'm open for recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindle is not the only ereader to have an eink screen, in fact every device that is marketed as ereader (and not i.e. a more generic tablet) uses this technology.

Said that, basically every ereader available today can do the things that you need; I think that the real choice when speaking about scientific books that contain math and formulas is about the ebook format, not about the ereader: reflowable text formats like Amazon's `.azw` and everyone else's `.epub` can get the job done, but maybe for some more complex layouts, a fixed page format like `.pdf` could be a better choice. It really depends on the specific book and how well is formatted.

Choosing an ereader and a brand is more a choice of an ecosystem rather than about differences in the hardware (all of them, more or less, are equivalent and have the same features); Amazon Kindle is maybe the more closed platform, meaning that it uses its own file formats, while the rest of the world uses the *de facto* standard `.epub`.

You can also try to have a look at these questions:

- [Dedicated ebook reader?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/1024/136)
- [Reader for scientific papers - what should I look for?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/1224/136)
- [What 's the best way to read a scientific PDF?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/1279/136)

Comment: I generally agree with this answer. Just wanted to add that LED tablets have some way to reduce glare and  switch into night mode or reduce exposure to blue light that contributes to insomnia (for example: Twilight for Android). Kindle is intended for general reader (and it's practically a monopoly), so I wouldn't expect it to develop these features for the academic market that quickly. The only other option is a larger size e-ink tablet which reads PDFs, but so far these have been pricey.