# Things to consider for choosing an e-ink pdf ereader for science books and papers

Tags: ebook-readers, pdf, e-ink

I have taken a look at A4 size e-ink ebook readers for pdf files.

I have found five models:

- SONY DPT RP1
- Good e-reader 13.3"
- Onyx Boox Max Carta
- Dasung
- Icarus A4

And there is Remarkable, but that is only 10" large.

They have quite the same price, around 700 $.

On what properties should I evaluate these models, if I want to read scientific books and research papers on them?

There are some advice at

[Looking for recommendation on eBook reader for university textbooks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/looking-for-recommendation-on-ebook-reader-for-university-textbooks)

[Dedicated ebook reader?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/dedicated-ebook-reader)

[Reader for scientific papers - what should I look for?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/reader-for-scientific-papers-what-should-i-look-for)

[What 's the best way to read a scientific PDF?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/what-s-the-best-way-to-read-a-scientific-pdf)

[Reader for scientific papers - what should I look for?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/reader-for-scientific-papers-what-should-i-look-for)

What other properties should I look for in this ebook reader market niche?

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to e-ink? I have a 12 inch x 8 inch Galaxy Tab Pro 12 that meets your needs well, plus you can use the Kindle app and Google Play app. I paid $300-350 for it 2 years ago. I realize that e-ink has many advantages, but tablets (especially android) offer a variety of reading apps, color for about half the price for high end models.

Comment: Thanks, that's an aspect I did not think of. A reason to have e-ink is to have longer working hours.

Comment: the vast majority of tech "books" are, unfortunately, PDF's.

Answer (score 2):

In a personal conversation, somebody raised my attention to the following concerns:

- many ebooks have colourful pictures and diagrams, so a black-and-white e-ink display might not be suitable for all documents and a tablet could come handy
- one does not want multiple devices but one portable thing, that has a proper web browser

I'm still in favor of a large e-ink reader but these are valid concerns.