# Ebook reader with pdf markup capabilities for reading outside

Tags: ebook-readers

I have an iPad with an app called GoodReader, which allows me to decently mark up scientific articles. Yet, even a little bit of sun renders it useless.

With kindle — my cousin has one — you can read in the sun, but it seems the capabilities for marking up scientific articles are nigh on non existent.

It seems like [ReMarkable](https://remarkable.com/store) might be excellent, but the price tag (>620Dollars) is forbidding.

Any suggestions below 300Euros?

Comment: This question from a month or two ago gives some possible options: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7434/things-to-consider-for-choosing-an-e-ink-pdf-ereader-for-science-books-and-paper

Comment: FYI, for future reference, "shopping-oriented" questions are generally discouraged on SE. See https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I assume that what you really want is information about available devices at a certain time with a given form factor -- and is somewhat on topic.

Comment: @idiotprogrammer Thank you very much. What do you mean by "form factor"? I am just asking about a device with certain capabilities that I can still afford. Is that already too shopping oriented? Should I avoid any reference to money? It would be of great help to find one substantially cheaper than the remarkable